# Asp Core API. Policy RequireAuthenticatedUser does not allow authenticated user after publishing on Linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using JWT tokens and policy:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("AllAuthenticated", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser());
            });
```

This works locally on Windows and Mac development environments:

```
[HttpPost("log-out")]
        [Authorize(Policy = "AllAuthenticated")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LogOut(){}
```

Logged in user is able to hit endpoints with  [Authorize(Policy = "AllAuthenticated")]. Not logged in user can not.

However after publishing to Linux: 
User is still able to Login but can not hit actions decorated with [Authorize(Policy = "AllAuthenticated")]: returns 401 Unauthorized.

On Login User receives JWT  token, which is sent back to the backend in each next request in the request header: Authorization: Bearer [*token here*].

I checked the token is exactly the same that was sent from backend core.
[image]

This behavior is seen on 2 Linux machines, so I guess it may be related to publishing to a Linux environment:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o /home/[user folder]/[publishing folder]
```

Token creation:

```
var tokeOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "mysite.com",
                audience: "myClientApp",
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(KEY_EXPIRATION_TIME),
                signingCredentials: signinCredentials
            );
            var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokeOptions);
            return tokenString;
```

Can someone at least point how I can debug the issue on those Linux machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in policy. Adding JWT `AuthenticationScheme` solved the issue.

Before:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {               
options.AddPolicy("AllAuthenticated", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser()); });
```

After:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {               
     options.AddPolicy("AllAuthenticated", 
        policy => policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).
                RequireAuthenticatedUser());});
```